# How to use sed command to read to return error if one of the line has unmatch pattern?

Tags: sed

I tried to look for any un-match on each line using `sed` comment. If any line not matching the pattern, then return 1, if all lines success. It looks for the pattern of -. I have the sed command as follow:

```
sed -n -E '/([a-zA-Z ]+-[0-9]+)/ p'
```

success case:

```
u-3 abaklsd
a-2 jkds
```

fail case:

```
u-3 abaklsd
a-2 jkds
khs jkd
```

Comment: `! grep -qv '-'`?

Comment: By `return 1` - do you mean `print 1` or `exit with status 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` does not have a facility for this. You can probably refactor your script to Perl with a small effort.

```
perl -ne 'if (/[a-zA-Z ]+-\d+/) { print } else { $rc=1; }
    exit $rc if (eof)'
```

Or Awk:

```
awk '{ if (/[a-zA-Z +-[0-9]+/) print; else rc=1 }
    END { exit rc }'
```

The parentheses are superfluous so I took them out. Perhaps you want leading `^` and trailing `$` anchors on the regex, though.